# Behaviour on html_safe? in Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-safe

I am trying to use the `html_safe?` method to check if a string/text which is retrieved from the DB contains any HTML. However, the `html_safe?` method is not returning the value I expected. Let's look at the following examples:

```
>> 'this is a string'.html_safe?
false

>> '<strong>this is a string</strong>'.html_safe?
false
```

I would expect the first invocation of `html_safe?` to return `true`, and the second invocation to return `false`. The results on the Rails console return `false` on both of the invocations...

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `html_safe?` or there is a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, the `html_safe?` method only return a boolean value that to indicate whether or not the type/object itself is html safe.

Therefore, it doesn't really matter what the contents are within a string, the `html_safe?` method would also return false for String type.